# How do make faster query from pandas to postgresql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I have a CSV file and I have to search if which rows are in the database.
for example, from my CSV I have to use name, surname, and birthdate to find the university name in DB.
For example:

[image]

[image]

from this image example, I should find XXX YYY study in university 1, AAA BBB in university 2, and no result for TTT YYY.

My solution is following which is very slow. CSV file has a 50k line and DB 40M.

I use python pandas, and read CSV files, then I create a new column combine of the name, surname, and birthdate. example data from the new combine column: "XXX+YYYY+29-05-1953"

Then I get a list of all possible data from the new combine column.
Lets say list is: `combine_list = data[new_column].tolist()`

And now my amazing query :))

```
query = Select concat(name ,'+',surname,'+',birthdate) as new_column, university
        from db_table where name is not NULL and surname is not NULL and birthdate is not NULL
        and concat(name ,'+',surname,'+',birthdate) in {tuple(combine_list)}"
```

Could you please give me the advice to find them faster?

Answer (score 0):

You could query the columns as a tuple:

```sql
Select concat(name ,'+',surname,'+',birthdate) as new_column, university
from db_table
where (name, surname, birthdate) IN (('XXX', 'YYY', '29-05-53'),
                                     ('AAA', 'BBB', '01-01-1997'), ...)
```

This should be faster than querying against concatenated values, especially if there is an index over the columns in the `WHERE` clause.